# Repair/Recover data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb, repair

I have a big problem with a MySQL database stored on my raspberry (InnoDB engine). 
I'm not very expert in this field but I'll try to explain to you the problem.

MySQL crash everytime that I try to start it and I need to recover the data stored inside the DB.
The error is:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I just tried to start MySQL with the innodb_force_recovery flag from 1 to 6 but it still crashing. From the log I understood that the problem is a corruption inside some tables.

I tried to check my database file with https://recovery.twindb.com/ and it shows that some tables inside "mysql" database need to be recovered and the tables inside "production" database (the mine) are ok, indeed I can see all my data on this website.
How can easly recover my data? There is some free tools or script that I can use? 
I have all files as ibdata01, *.frm, *.ibd

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Undrop for InnoDB](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb) a tool behind recovery.twindb.com.
To recover corrupt database you need to follow steps from https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Parse the ibd file:

```
# ./stream_parser -f /var/lib/mysql/sakila/actor.ibd
```

The dump records from the PRIMARY index:

```
# ./c_parser -6f pages-actor.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000015.page \
    -t sakila/actor.sql \
    > dumps/default/actor 2>&1 dumps/default/actor_load.sql
```

Then load the dump:

```
# mysql --local-infile sakila < dumps/default/actor_load.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to some major changes In IBD file. It maybe corrupted.

**Solution** - Recreate the structure from the FRM files.

MySQL provides a utility named “mysqlfrm” to recreate the table structure. This utility extracts the structure and creates a “Create table” script.
mysqlfrm –server=root:mypassword@localhost –port=3311 “<source/path>/mytable.frm” > “<destination/path>/recovered_mytable.sql”

The port in the instruction is not the port of MySQL server, it is any available port. The end of the script is meant to redirect the output in a file.

If, the give solution does not work, Please visit the [complete guide of How to restore tables from .IBD file.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-restore-tables-from-ibd-file-priyanka-chouhan/)

Thanks